# Bootstrap ignores custom div class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying this bootstrap snippet: [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category)

On my local computer everything running fine:
[image]

And this is result from hosted website:
[image]

As you can see button styles disappeared and picture list margin bottom zero..

style.css:

`.gallery_product
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}`

html:

```
 <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
```

i don't know if bootstrap overwrites something or if it's web host fault because on local computer everything working good.

Comment: Have you checked in devtools that your new styles are applied? Or that your class is even in the CSS? Could the browser be caching old styles?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Sounds like the stylesheet isn't being loaded, open Network in Dev Tools and find out if it's loaded

Comment: Thanks guys ! im stupid..